# How to manage this Bootstrap Nav?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
                </div>  
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>          
                    </ul>       
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I have this normal Bootstrap nav on my website. I added the active class to the first link and i can change the class when clicked on other links. But when i click `<a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>` the active class stays on the previous link but doesnt change to `<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>`. Also in mobile view i would like to change the default style where we can click outside the menu to close it.I have managed to close it when a link is pressed.

Comment: <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a> is not part of navbar
you will have to write jquery on click function to remove class from navbar menu.

Comment: How to change it sorry i`m new here

Comment: In Bootstrap nav they use javascript for menu button toggling only, not for the menu navigation indicators. For those you have to write your jquery code.

Comment: I have managed to close the menu when a link is clicked which isn't default but i can`t manage to close the menu when we click outside the menu...

Answer (score 0):

don't write active class in an element, let your script do it for you.you know CSS selectors already like :active,:visited,:hover etc define a script to check if  tag is active and append active class in the element.

Comment: could you please give me an example on how to do it. I`m a beginner in jQuery.

Comment: $(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href
.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $("a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});


this should do,make sure you are using jquery

Comment: thank you and i have managed by adding some ids and using click function to remove class and add class.

Comment: But my website is a single page where i gave ids to sections to scroll down. how to change class on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Navbars require a wrapping .navbar and a color scheme.
Navbars and their contents are fluid by default. Use optional containers to limit their horizontal width.
Use .pull-*-left and .pull-*-right to quickly align sub-components.
Ensure accessibility by using a  element or, if using a more generic element such as a , add a role="navigation" to every navbar to explicitly identify it as a landmark region for users of assistive technologies.